# FlowableEmitter fails to emit the items

Tags: rx-java2

I have a program which polls 2 directories - dir1 and dir2 and emit the file as soon as the file arrives in any of the 2 directories. But when the files arrive at same time in both directories, some files from either of the directory is failed to get emitted.

The code is as follows:

```
Flowable.create((FlowableEmitter<Path> em) -> pollDirectory(Arrays.asList(dir1,dir2), em),
              BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).subscribe();
```

The method pollDirectory has the below code:

```
for (Path directory: pathList) {

    FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
    fao.addListener(new FileAlterationListenerImpl(emitter));
    final FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(5000);
    monitor.addObserver(fao);
    try {
         monitor.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         handleException(e);
    }
}
```

The FileAlterationListenerImpl class emits the path on file creation and code is as follows:

```
public class FileAlterationListenerImpl implements FileAlterationListener {
  FlowableEmitter<Path> source;

  public FileAlterationListenerImpl(FlowableEmitter<Path> emitter) {
    super();
    this.source = emitter;
  }

  @Override
  public void onFileCreate(final File file) {
    source.onNext(file.toPath());
  }
    
}
```

Is there any way in RxJava to handle this scenario so that emitter emits files from both directories even if the files are arrived at same time?

Answer (score 0):

`FileAlterationObserver` creates a thread that will trigger its emission thus if you have two or more, that will result in concurrent `onNext` invocation.

The [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/FlowableEmitter.html) indicates this is not safe and you need to use `serialize()` to ensure thread safety.

```java
Flowable.create((FlowableEmitter<Path> em) ->
     pollDirectory(Arrays.asList(dir1,dir2), em.serialize()),
     BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER
)
.subscribe();
```